# Cloning repository from local server missing commits

Tags: git

**--- Some background ---**

I am running multiple docker containers on my server, each of them does `git fetch` on startup. The purpose is to update an in-docker repository (from *github*), since its state may be old, depending on the last time the docker image was built.

I tried an optimization to save internet throughput:

1. Update a local repository on the **host** machine (from *github*).
2. Then on each docker `git remote set-url origin user@host_machine:/path/to/host/local/repo; git fetch`

It turns out however that some updates are missing on the docker repositories. Tried it without docker, happens as well.

**--- End of background ---**

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Clone a repository from github to local repo A.
2. Clone local repo A to another local repo B.
3. Update some commits on github.
4. `Git fetch` on local repo A.
5. `Git fetch` on local repo B.

At the end, some commits are found on A but not on B. (`git log` on `origin/master` shows different HEAD between A and B).

Comment: In step 3, did you only do a `fetch` or did you fast forward the local branches so their history matches the remote?

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to comment the answer is obvious.

On local repo A - `origin/master` refers to the master branch on github.

On local repo B - `origin/master` refers to the local master branch on repo A. After all `origin` is repo A.

So one must pull the branches on repo A in order to be able to see them on repo B. Thats it.